# react-select dropdown not visible

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select to create a dropdown for an open-source application which uses React/Redux and Electron. I'm using the bog-standard example code provided by react-select for this. However, when running, while the select box shows, clicking it seemingly does nothing. The dropdown that's meant to appear does not. When inspecting the HTML sources, it shows that when it's clicked, something does appear in the HTML, but this isn't visible in the app.

This is quite a large application and I don't know how much value there is in posting snippets of code; this one file alone is 500LoC. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening though?

Comment: Does your elements have a width / height? if not , try that

Comment: Using the debugger I found the dropdown element when the box is clicked. The element is in the HTML, but does not appear on-screen. I don't know why it's not appearing though. The max-height is 300px and the width seems to be relative to its parent div/the size of the window.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the "overflow" option of the CSS was set to "hidden" by default. Setting this to "visible" in the CSS resolved this and now I the box appears as intended.

If anyone else has a similar issue, pause the application at runtime using the "debugger" command in console and check the CSS stylings of the element in question. I found this by accident but could help for future!